# Pygame button issue; won't display next stage when button clicked

Tags: python, button, pygame, pygame-surface

Building a simple Pygame where after you hit the start button and go to level 1; a door appears and by clicking on the door it calls the function which contains the code for the 2nd level of the game. But when the door button is clicked the function is called for a quick instant and then it goes back to level 1. How would I fix this? Only included relevant code : (game loop, level functions and Button class.

```
main_menu = True

class Button():
  def __init__(self,x,y,image):
    self.image = image
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
    self.rect.x = x 
    self.rect.y = y 
    self.clicked = False 
   
  def draw(self):
    action = False
    
    #get mouse position
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
      if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
        action = True 
        self.clicked = True 

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
      self.clicked = False 

    #draw Button 
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect) 

    return action

 
#create buttons 
start_button = Button(screen_width // 2 -350, screen_height // 2, start_img) 
cancel_button = Button(screen_width // 2 + 150, screen_height // 2, cancel_img)
closed_door_button = Button(370,0,closedDoor)



def level1():
  draw_bg()
  player.draw()
  draw_oMG()  
  if player.rect.x >= 440 and player.rect.x <= 460 and player.rect.y >= 30 and player.rect.y <=80:
    draw_oMGM1()

def level2():
 draw_house()
 player.draw() 

running = True
while running:
    
  if main_menu == True: 
    
    if start_button.draw():
      main_menu = False
    if cancel_button.draw():
      running = False 
  else:  
    level1()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x>5:
      player.face = "left"
      player.facing()
      player.rect.x -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.rect.x<790:
      player.face = "right" 
      player.facing()
      player.rect.x += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.rect.y>10:
      player.face = "up"
      player.facing()
      player.rect.y -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]and player.rect.y<395:
      player.face = "down" 
      player.facing()
      player.rect.y += 5
    if closed_door_button.draw():
      level2()
           
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
  
  pygame.display.update() 
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Main loop simplified:

```py
while running:
    if main_menu == True: 
        main_menu()
    else:  
        level1()
        if closed_door_button.draw():
            level2()
        ...
```

So, if you are not in the main menu, you are constantly drawing the first level.

If you click on the door, *at this exact frame*, the second level will be drawn on top of the first level. The next frame, the event does not occur anymore, and the first level is drawn alone.

To avoid that issue, create a variable `level` which stores the current level. Then simply draw the appropriate level according to the variable:

```py
level = 1

while running:
    if main_menu: # you can remove "== True"
        main_menu()
    else:
        if level == 1: # first level
            level1()
        elif level == 2: # second level
            level2()
        if closed_door_button.draw():
            level += 1
```

---

Also, you can simplify your code by using the list returned by `pygame.event.get()` to get when the door is clicked:

```py
class Button():
    def draw(self, event_list):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect) 

        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            return True
        return False

...

while running:
    # use the same event list so that both can catch the same events
    event_list = pygame.event.get():
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    ...
    if closed_door_button(event_list):
        level += 1
```